# Link on published action with opengraph

Tags: hyperlink, action, facebook-opengraph

I've a trouble with my link on published action.

When my action is published, the link appear like that:

```
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%myDomain.com%2F%3Ffb_action_ids%3D3085543269620%26fb_action_types%3Dvideo.watches%26fb_source%3Drecent_activity&h=dAQF21zjX&enc=AZP6SPsPIfAKMoNKqLKjTEig1nsAERVmwUcrfURxEHA34JS11i5ofB29bXKBaOrkm0cOv-Lyg5IVTth3Kr308Qar
```

And I see on another app who used the same action, the link appear like that:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=XXXXXXX&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FTheDomain.com%3Ffb_action_ids%3D3056990355815%26fb_action_types%3Dvideo.watches%26fb_source%3Drecent_activity&response_type=token&display=page&auth_referral=1
```

Did you know why we haven't not the same publish link type ?

I want to publish with an URL like that: http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=XXXXXXX&m.....

Best regards, sorry for my poor english :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link of the first type appears when a users click on a link which will take them to an external site.

The link of the 2nd type appears if the app has enabled Authenticated Referrals in the app's settings. When a user click a link of this type, Facebook links into the Authentication Dialog to generate an access token or OAuth code, the user is then redirected to the Action URL.

Comment: What should I modify "Authenticated Referrals" in the application ? I don't find this on setting panel :/

Comment: Oh, I've found !! Thank you so much ;)